# Build error when dynamic keyword in generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have generic interface:

```
public interface IItemDownloader<TResult>
{
   //FROM:  TResult Do<TResult>();
   //TO:
    TResult Do();
}
```

I have few implementations like this what causing error:

```
public class DynamicItemDownloader : IItemDownloader<dynamic>
```

When I use it like

```
using (IItemDownloader<dynamic> d = new DynamicItemDownloader())
{
    // i get error during build 
    /*
        Cannot implicitly convert type 'DynamicItemDownloader' to 'IItemDownloader<dynamic>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
    */
}
```

Mystery is that when I am using Visual Studio 2013 U5 RC I get this error. When I try to build it by TFS I get the same error.
When I use Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise I do not get any error and I am able to execute code.
When I want to have build-able code from VS2013 and TFS I have to use

```
using (var d = new DynamicItemDownloader())
{
    // this is buildable from TFS and VS2013 without error
}
```

It is mystery for me. Know someone why I get this error? Can someone explain where I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are you defining the `TResult` on the interface and on the `Do` method?  Note right now the type defined on the interface isn't even used.

Comment: When you use VS2015, are you using C#6 vs C#5 in 2013? Could it be a covariance change between C# versions?

Comment: In addition to @juharr, you should not define `TResult` twice. After that, you should also probably be defining your using like `using (var d = new DynamicItemDownloader())`, unless there is a good reason you want to cast up to the interface?

Comment: @juharr Sorry i added bad definition for Do Method.. TResult is Defined on Interface level not on Method level.

Comment: @Dave Zych In both VS 2013 and VS2015 i am using .Net 4.5 and language i have set to default but when set language to C#5 i have still build-able code.

Comment: @Ron Beyer I do not need to use interface reference i mean i can use var but i just wan to know why in VS 2015 it is working and in VS2013 no.